# What is the source of this Nietzsche quote?

Tags: nietzsche

I am looking for the original German translation of the following quote.

> To experience a thing as beautiful means: to experience it necessarily wrongly,” Friedrich Nietzsche wrote in The Will to Power
>   https://usaonlinepress.com/2019/09/09/misunderstanding-susan-sontag/

Do you know where in the text to find it?

Comment: When you say "original German translation", do you mean the original German version of the quote (not a translation since he was writing in German), or do you just want to know exactly where in the English translations of his writings the quote can be found, and the exact wording of the translation?

Comment: Are you confident in the accuracy of the translation? What would Nietzsche have meant by that?

Comment: "*Ein Ding als schön empfinden heißt: es nothwendig falsch empfinden*", [Der Wille zur Macht](https://nietzsche.ralfj.de/willeBJ.pdf), 10[167], 270 (p.192).

Comment: @Mark Andrews -- That translation is from p. 424 of The Will to Power (a book assembled from parts of his notebooks after his death), and it's translated almost the same way on [p. 203 of Nietzsche: Writings from the Late Notebooks](https://books.google.com/books?id=PlnFmMRufOkC&lpg=PA203&ots=nybLRRt0D7&dq=nietzsche%20%22experience%20a%20thing%20as%20beautiful%22&pg=PA203#v=onepage&q=nietzsche%20%22experience%20a%20thing%20as%20beautiful%22&f=false) from Cambridge University Press, you can read some of the context on p. 202 of the sections available on google books.

Comment: I hoped to find the original German from the source of the English translation at least. One elucidation of the translation is provided in the linked New Yorker article.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ein Ding als schön empfinden heißt: es nothwendig falsch empfinden. 
[(*Nachgelasse Fragmente*, Herbst 1887, eKGWB)](http://www.nietzschesource.org/#eKGWB/NF-1887,8)